# Add Product Taxonomy Terms To Image Alt & Title

Tags: php, function, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to add the product title and some taxonomy terms to the image alt and image title text on the front end. I can add the product title with the function below but I'd like to append the taxonomy terms from the default woocommerce product_cat and also some custom taxonomies outlined below:

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'change_attachement_image_attributes', 20, 2);

function change_attachement_image_attributes( $attr, $attachment ){

    // Get post parent
    $parent = get_post_field( 'post_parent', $attachment);

    // Bail if it's not a product or if admin
    $type = get_post_field( 'post_type', $parent);
    if( is_admin() || $type != 'product' ){
        return $attr;
    }

    // Get title
    $title = get_post_field( 'post_title', $parent);

    // Get Product Category
    $product_cat = get_the_terms($post->ID,'product_cat');

    // Get Artwork Category
    $artwork_cat = get_the_terms($post->ID,'artwork-category');

    // Get Artwork Materials
    $artwork_material = get_the_terms($post->ID,'artwork-materials');

    $attr['alt'] = $title;
    $attr['title'] = $title;

    return $attr;
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to output something like:

"$title, a $artwork_cat by $product_cat. $artwork_material" (E.g. The Mona Lisa, a painting by Leonardo Da Vinci. Oil on board.)

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the product id to the `get_the_terms` function which is you already getting in `$parent`. Try the below code.

```
function change_attachement_image_attributes( $attr, $attachment ){

    // Get post parent
    $parent = get_post_field( 'post_parent', $attachment);

    // Bail if it's not a product or if admin
    $type = get_post_field( 'post_type', $parent);
    
    if( is_admin() || $type != 'product' ){
        return $attr;
    }

    // Get title
    $title = get_post_field( 'post_title', $parent);

    // Get Product Category
    $product_cat = get_the_terms($parent,'product_cat');

    // Get Artwork Category
    $artwork_cat = get_the_terms($parent,'artwork-category');

    // Get Artwork Materials
    $artwork_material = get_the_terms($parent,'artwork-materials');

    $title = $title.', a'.$artwork_cat.' by '.$product_cat[0]->name.'. '.$artwork_material.'.';

    $attr['alt'] = $title;
    $attr['title'] = $title;

    return $attr;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'change_attachement_image_attributes', 20, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you Bhautik! This works perfectly. In the instances where there are multiple terms it returns 'Array' but I just alter these to get the first term as you've done with $product_cat